# Authenticating is taking me to a profile edit page

Tags: javascript, api, uber-api

When am authenticating my app with https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&response_type=code&redirect_uri="+REDIRECT_URI

The app asks the user to log in .. successfully logging in however doesnt retutrn "code" and the user is brought to a strange edit profile page with editable First Name, Last Name, Email and Password.

Any idea why this would happen?

The result should be code="9824793847928374928734" appended to the URI if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hello, this is a bug on the Uber side. It should be resolved within the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

This was an Uber side bug which has been resolved. Your oauth code should now be working correctly.